# Is it possible having this type error in Flutter even if this part was copied from pub.dev? How can I solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make this stopwatch app and on the page:
https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer

I have found the example but I have two specific lines of code which raise this error, which refers to the third line of the reported code.

```
The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
```

```dart
builder: (context, snap) {
       final value = snap.data;
       final displayTime = StopWatchTimer.getDisplayTime(value); 
...
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The example probably was never updated for null-safety.  You should file a bug against the package about it.  You need to check if `value` is `null` before you use it.  For example: `...getDisplayTime(value ?? 0)` or, if `value` is guaranteed to never be `null`, ...getDisplayTime(value!)`.

Answer (score 0):

int and int? is different data type. int? can be null and int not. you can convert int? using ! or ??. example intVar! or intVar ?? 0